# regex issue c# numbers are underscores now

Tags: c#, regex

My Regex is removing all numeric (0-9) in my string.
I don't get why all numbers are replaced by _

EDIT: I understand that my "_" regex pattern changes the characters into underscores. But not why numbers!

Can anyone help me out? I only need to remove like all special characters.

See regex here:

```
 string symbolPattern = "[!@#$%^&*()-=+`~{}'|]";
Regex.Replace("input here 12341234" , symbolPattern, "_");

Output: "input here ________"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your pattern uses a dash in the middle, which acts as a range of the ascii characters from `)` to `=`. Here's a breakdown:

- `)`: 41
- `1`: 49
- `=`: 61

As you can see, numbers start at 49, and falls between the range of 41-61, so they're matched and replaced.

You need to place the `-` at either the beginning or end of the character class for it to be matched literally rather than act as a range:

```
"[-!@#$%^&*()=+`~{}'|]"
```

Comment: Thanks, to all. I have to choose one as the answer and this one is the one most detailed which explained the issue. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

you must escape `-` because sequence `[)-=]` contains digits

```
string symbolPattern = "[!@#$%^&*()\-=+`~{}'|]";
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `-` to the end of the list so it is seen as a literal:

```
"[!@#$%^&*()=+`~{}'|-]"
```

Or, to the *front*:

```
"[-!@#$%^&*()=+`~{}'|]"
```

As it stands, it will match all characters in the range `)-=`, which includes all numerals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your special characters in your regex.  For instance, * is a wildcard match. Look at what some of those special characters mean for your match.

Comment: Correct for escaping (especially for the "-"), but `*` means "0 or more", not "any character".

Answer (score 0):

I've not used C#, but typically the "*" character is also a control character that would need escaping.

The following matches a whole line of any characters, although the "^" and "$" are some what redundant:

```
^.*$
```

This matches any number of "A" characters that appear in a string:

```
A*
```

The "Owl" book from oreilly is what you really need to research this:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do?green=B5B9A1A7-B828-5E41-9D38-70AF661901B8&intcmp=af-mybuy-9780596528126.IP

Comment: It is a regex metacharacter, and you're right that it matches any number of times, however this is not the case when it occurs inside a character class. This literally matches an asterisk: `[*]`.